# How to intercept HTTP Request in Perl?

Tags: perl, http, httprequest

I am developing a web application and I am wondering if there is a way or some kind of module that can intercept or handle any HTTP Request before being displayed to the client. I can't modify the httpd.conf file so it isn't an option.
I want to do this for adding some security to my web app by denying the access or redirecting to other pages or by modifying the response sent to the client and some other stuff.
I've also heard about Request Dispatching and maybe it could help me.
Anybody knows how to achieve this?

Comment: You must provide more info: which frameworks/modules; how it works (cgi/fastcgi/mod_perl); how response is sent to client etc

Comment: I just want to know a way to intercept HTTP Request, that's all. I'm using mod_perl but I can't made any change to it and I'm not using any framework.

Comment: If you're using mod_perl, then you have full access to the Apache request lifecycle.  http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/http.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [Plack::Handler::Apache2](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aHandler%3a%3aApache2) to enable PSGI support. From there, you can PSGI Middleware modules to modify both the request and response.

It's hard to get more specific without knowing how you've setup Perl to be executed in your mod_perl environment.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/~book/HTTP-Proxy-0.25/lib/HTTP/Proxy.pm), a [perl](http://perl.cpan.org) module to write a web proxy... An example of this:

```
 # alternate initialisation
  my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new;
  $proxy->port( 3128 ); # the classical accessors are here!

  # this is a MainLoop-like method
  $proxy->start;
  my $d = HTTP::Daemon->new || die;
  while (my $c = $d->accept) {
      while (my $r = $c->get_request) {
          if ($r->method eq 'GET' and $r->uri->path eq "/xyzzy") {
              # remember, this is *not* recommended practice :-)
              $c->send_file_response("/home/hd1/.zshrc");
          }
          else {
              $c->send_error(RC_FORBIDDEN)
          }
      }
      $c->close;
      undef($c);
  }
```